# Como eu posso chamar um programa.py em um servidor dentro de outro programa.py local?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, bash

Eu tenho interagido com um servidor dentro de um programa que estou fazendo usando a função os.system() como se estivesse usando o proprio console.

```
os.system("ssh user@192.168.0.101 'comando a ser realizado'")
```

Para tudo que tinha feito antes(criar pastas, mover arquivos e coisas no genero) essa função vinha funcionado, agora quando eu faço.

```
os.system("ssh user@192.168.0.101 'python programa.py'")
```

Ele parece que lançou o programa, porém não dá nenhum retorno, e ao que parece sequer está executando.

Comment: Talvez a biblioteca [`fabric`](http://www.fabfile.org/) te ajude em alguma coisa

Comment: programa.py está no servidor destino ou no servidor que está executando o ssh.

Comment: Adicione o argumento `-t` que vai funcionar. Exemplo: `os.system("ssh -t user@192.168.0.101 'python programa.py'")`